# Supervisorctl error: unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock refused connection?

Tags: unix, supervisord

This is my config flie.I run `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` it works well.
When I try to run `supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`,the error happened:

Error: , Unknown protocol for serverurl /var/run/supervisord.sock: file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0b2-py2.7.egg/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 440

I can start or stop my program through `http://127.0.0.1:9001` perfectly,but I want to control the program in the command line.Anyone can help me?

```
[unix_http_server]
file = /var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod = 0777
chown= root:cruelcage

[inet_http_server]
port=9001
username = cruelcage
password = 123

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = /var/run/supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/cruelcage/log/supervisord/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=true              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
#user=root                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
childlogdir=/home/cruelcage/log/supervisord/            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[program:config]
command=python /home/cruelcage/documents/config/config.py
autostart = true
startsecs = 5
user = cruelcage
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 20MB
stdoiut_logfile_backups = 20
stdout_logfile = /home/cruelcage/log/debug.log
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `[supervisorctl]` `serverurl` should be "**unix://**/var/run/supervisord.sock", since "/var/run/supervisord.sock" is not a valid URI for `xmlrpclib` to connect to.

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes supervisor configuration file is not automatically generated after installation and you have to write it manually:

```
echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
sudo supervisorctl status
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and found that it occurred after a server restart. When supervisor tried to restart afterwards, **it couldn't find the log directory** that was specified in my daemon config file (this problem didn't appear while supervisor was running).

All I needed to do was change the **stdout_logfile** path (or comment out the line) in my file:

*(swap the ##### for your file id)*

`sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/daemon-#####.conf`

Add an existing log file path or comment the line out with a # at the start of the line:

`#stdout_logfile=/my/bad/log/directory`

Then restart supervisor

`sudo service supervisor restart`

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. Who knew the error was about the log file not found?